# How to add Vuetify to astro?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, astrojs

I'm having trouble adding Vuetify 3 to Astro when using the Vue integration.
This is what I have so far:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

import vue from '@astrojs/vue';

import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [vue()],
  vite: {
    ssr: {
      noExternal: ['vuetify'],
    },
    plugins: [vuetify()],
  },
});
```

I'm getting the `'Vuetify plugin must be loaded after the vue plugin'` error.
Don't know how to move on from here. I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: Having the same issue! Just found this example in the Astro discord: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vjbdds](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vjbdds) ... worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

The configs in the Astro integrations ([`@astrojs/vue`](https://github.com/withastro/astro/blob/f0f6a33/packages/integrations/vue/src/index.ts) in this case) are appended to your own Astro config, so the `vuetify` plugin would be registered first here.

A workaround is to define your own [Astro integration](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/integrations-reference/) that calls [`updateConfig()`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/integrations-reference/#updateconfig-option) to add Vuetify:

```js
// astro.config.mjs
import vuetifyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';

/**
 * Vuetify integration for Astro
 * @param {import('astro/config').Options} options
 * @returns {import('astro/config').AstroIntegration}
 */
function vuetify(options) {
  return {
    name: 'my-astro-vuetify-integration',
    hooks: {
      'astro:config:setup': ({ updateConfig }) => {
        updateConfig({
          vite: {
            ssr: {
              noExternal: ['vuetify'],
            },
            plugins: [vuetifyPlugin()],
          },
        });
      },
    },
  }
}
```

And install it *after* the Vue integration:

```js
// astro.config.mjs
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    vue(),
    vuetify(),
  ],
})
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. This changes the error to something related to Vuetify. I guess I'm gonna have to wait for the community to build or document the process before I can use Vuetify in Astro.

Comment: This solution did work except that the CSS aren't loading properly. Especially in the console it says vars are not set. Will have to look for a workaround.